# How to recreate the lighting of a reference illustration, with low sun and pink shades on the mountains

Tags: rendering, lighting

I am fairly new to blender and am wanting to create this particular lighting.

I can do the background in illustrator so it's just the pinky kinda light I'm having trouble with.

[image]

Answer (score 4):

I was able to recreate it with **two lights, a (lightly emitting) backdrop, and a very dark, but slightly violet tinted, world**.

[image]

#### Breakdown

- The lights are *Area lamps* with a fairly big size (for soft shadows), illuminating from the two sides, slightly towards the horizon. One is bright pink/orange (750W), the other is a slightly less bright (500W) blue/violet.

  <sup>An alternative, if you'd like to have more realistic shadows, is a three-light setup, with one sharper, brighter pink light coming from the direction of the sun: see pic below ↓</sup>

  [image]
- The world, as you can see, is dark violet (because the ground in the foreground is in a violet shade).
- The backdrop is just an image with low relative emission (1.0). Actually I used a mesh plane and circle with a gradient texture.
- The ground is just a default principled material with no specularity.

I also used a high focal length (100mm) camera.

#### Results

(these are based on the two-light setup)

**Eevee**
[image]

**Cycles**
[image]

Note: I picked the backdrop color with the color picker from your reference image, but they appear duller in my render because I used the default Filmic *Color Management* settings. Depending on the kind of color you want to give to your scene, you might opt for a different color management scheme.

#### The file

This was created with an alpha version of Blender (2.82), so it may have compatibility issues.

[image]

Answer (score -1):

Maybe making the sun a low emission light could help.